# Is there anything wrong with this proposed proof of the irrationality of Euler's constant?

Tags: analysis

Let $\{\lambda_n\}$ be the sequence given by $H_n - \ln n$. We claim that $\lambda_n$ is irrational for every integer $n>1$ and justify this by the following argument:

Assume that $\lambda_k$ is rational for some integer $k>1$ such that $H_k - \ln k = p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are integers.

Rearranging the above we arrive at $H_k - p/q = \ln k$, which implies that $\ln k$ is rational since $H_k$ is rational. But we know that $\ln k$ is irrational for all integers $k>1$, hence we reach a contradiction.

Therefore, $\lambda_n$ is irrational for all integers $n>1$. Hence the limit as $n$ tends to infinity is irrational, and we are done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are implicitly claiming that the set of irrational numbers is closed in $\mathbb R$, which it is not. Indeed its closure is $\mathbb R$ (it is a dense subset), i.e. every real number is the limit of a sequence of irrational numbers.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, this is a really fascinating site ! And thanks Micah for the editions.

Answer (score 24):

You can have a rational limit of a sequence of all irrational numbers. Consider for example $\sqrt{2{\sqrt{2{\sqrt{2\ldots}}}}} = 2$

Comment: Well in this case, the type of definition of the sequence is different, isn't it ? May you please come up with a sequence whose definition is similar to that of Euler's constant ?

Comment: It would perhaps be too hard to define "similar" in the definition of Euler's constant in a way that could give a counter-example and satisfy your want for similarity. But if you look at the abstraction of your statement, in general, for any given real number $x$, whether rational or irrational, there are uncountably many possible sequences of purely irrational numbers $x_n$ that converge to $x$.

Comment: @Tatenda: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ is irrational for every $N$, but the sequence converges to zero.

Comment: It took me some time to verify that the limit is 2. I am getting old ;)

Comment: @CarstenS: The simplest way to see it is probably by noticing that the logarithm of left hand side is just $\log(2)\cdot (\sum_{n\geq 1} 2^{-n})$

Comment: @tomasz Or note that, if $x = \sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2...}}}$, then $x = \sqrt{2x}$

Answer (score 20):

For example,
$$
\lambda_n := e - \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}
$$
are all irrational numbers, but their limit is zero.

Comment: $\lambda_n := x/n$ also works, for any irrational $x$.